# What other standards are there than IEEE 315 and IPC?

Tags: components, schematics

What other standards are there than IEEE 315 and IPC for creating schematic symbols and component representations??

Answer (score 3):

[IEEE 315](http://www.simplecad.com/y32-symbol-library-ieee-std-315.htm), which you've already mentioned, is also known a [ANSI Y.32.2](http://tech-uofm.info/spring_2015/TECH1010/Visio/schem_intro.pdf). In addition there is [ANSI/IEEE Std 91/91a/991](http://www.ddpp.com/DDPP3_pdf/IEEEsyms.pdf) for logic symbols.

[IEC 60617](http://www.thedraughtingacademy.co.za/Library/Subject%20Resources/Electrical%20Draughting/IEC60617%20Symbols.pdf) (aka British Standard BS 3939) originally was used mostly for electromechanical drawings but has some electronic symbols as well and is a standard throughout Europe.

[This document](https://www.k-state.edu/edl/docs/pubs/technical-resources/Technote8.pdf) goes over some of the differences between standards, such as the difference between resistor symbols used in the US (IEEE 315) and Europe (IEC 60617):

[image]

This is the principal difference I have noticed when looking at various schematics on the 'net.

Comment: Great stuff!! Thank you!! Do you feel this encompasses the major standards documents?

Comment: @RobMcNeil I searched quite a bit and that's all I could find.  I think including both the logic symbols and the European standards should pretty well cover it.